# Groovy - Extract and display a substring from a String

Tags: groovy

I would like to find a pattern from the below string. All words containing "MATCH.TEXT3", possibly the latest one matching the ending number.

```
{MATCH.TEXT1.1=[1, admin, 07/10/14 09:29:34], MATCH.TEXT2.2=[2, admin, 07/10/14 10:01:08], MATCH.TEXT3.3=[3, admin, 07/10/14 10:08:01], MATCH.TEXT3.4=[4, admin, 07/10/14 11:08:01], MATCH=[TEXT3]}
```

Expected Output:

```
MATCH.TEXT3.4

or

MATCH.TEXT3.3
MATCH.TEXT3.4
```

Comment: What have You already tried?

Comment: Newbie to groovy, I did the long way using the string.find("MATCH.TEXT3.*"), then, splitting by ',' which results in multiple values

Comment: What is the source of the string?  looks like some `toString()` from a matcher or json.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use findAll() method on string to extract tokens that match given pattern:

```
String s = '{MATCH.TEXT1.1=[1, admin, 07/10/14 09:29:34], MATCH.TEXT2.2=[2, admin, 07/10/14 10:01:08], MATCH.TEXT3.3=[3, admin, 07/10/14 10:08:01], MATCH.TEXT3.4=[4, admin, 07/10/14 11:08:01], MATCH=[TEXT3]}'

List<String> tokens =  s.findAll(/MATCH\.TEXT3(\.[0-9]+)?/)

assert tokens == ['MATCH.TEXT3.3', 'MATCH.TEXT3.4']

String last = tokens.last()

assert last == 'MATCH.TEXT3.4'
```

Comment: This answered worked too, but I had to accept Haim's answer because, it gave me the last match too, which is what I was expecting

Comment: Getting last element is even easier:
String last = tokens.last() Check updated sample code. It's less noisy imho

Answer (score 2):

For last match:

```
class Finder {
    static main(args) {
        def str = '''<your string>'''
        def textFinder= /(MATCH.TEXT3.\d+)/
        def textMatcher = str=~textFinder
        if(textMatcher.size()>0){
            def lastMatch = (Integer) textMatcher.size() - 1
            println (textMatcher=textMatcher[lastMatch][1])         
        }
    }
}
```

Output:
MATCH.TEXT3.4

All matchs is an easy change.

Comment: Szymon's answer its cleaner.  I would check his answer. Keep my upvote for the effort ;-)